# I can't render two queries on node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

This is my code:

```
app.get('/listuser/:id',  function (req, res) {
  Utenti.find().then(listut => {res.render('listuser',{listut: listut}) })
  Utenti.findOne({ _id: req.user.id }, function (err, obj) { var imageIcone = (obj.image);
    res.render('listuser',{ imageIcone: imageIcone });
  })
})
```

The problem is that two renderings are not supported, I can't find a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design -- per the Express [render() documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render), render sends a response to the user (usually an HTML string generated by a templating engine). You can only send one response, and thus there is no way to render() multiple times.